# yii 1.1.x ar relation for composite forign key

Tags: for-loop, yii, relationship

I have three tables

```
Boooking
  id, -> primary key
  name 
Ticket 
  booking_id, (primary key)
  seq ,    (primary key)
  name 
TicketAllocation
  id, (primary key)
  booking_id, (foreign key)
  seq, (foreign key)
  name,
  date
```

Ticket table has primary key as composite of(booking_id,seq), and foreign key booking_id from Booking table.
and it works as foreign key in TicketAllocation table.
How can i define relation in both Ticket and TicketAllocation table so i can use AR relation to get related data.

Answer (score 0):

Hii it you can simply use this

```
Ticket  Model
    public function relations()
        {
        return array(
        'ticketToBoooking'    => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Boooking', 'booking_id'),
   );
}

TicketAllocation Model

    public function relations()
        {
            return array(
         'ticketAllcationToBooking'    => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Boooking', 'booking_id'),

    );
}
```